# Yii2 ActiveRecord : composite IN condition

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii2

How to write a composite IN condition like `(id, name) in ((1, 'George'), (2, 'Tom'))` when using ActiveRecord's `where()` condition ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> To create a composite IN condition you can use and array for the column name and value, where the values are indexed by the column name: `['in', ['id', 'name'], [['id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo'], ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'bar']]]`.

e.g. :

```
$models = Model::find()->where(['in', ['id', 'name'], [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'George'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Tom'],
]])->all();
```

Read more about [ActiveQuery::where()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail).

Comment: Get it. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `in` condition inside the `where()` method:

> in: operand 1 should be a column or DB expression. Operand 2 can be
>   either an array or a Query object. It will generate an IN condition.
>   If Operand 2 is an array, it will represent the range of the values
>   that the column or DB expression should be; If Operand 2 is a Query
>   object, a sub-query will be generated and used as the range of the
>   column or DB expression. For example, ['in', 'id', [1, 2, 3]] will
>   generate id IN (1, 2, 3). The method will properly quote the column
>   name and escape values in the range. The in operator also supports
>   composite columns. In this case, operand 1 should be an array of the
>   columns, while operand 2 should be an array of arrays or a Query
>   object representing the range of the columns.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#hash-format

Example:

```
Model::find()->where(['in', 'id', [1,2]])->all();
```

Comment: ```operand 1 should be a column or DB expression``` only one column ?